# Drupal.. images compression issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

for some reasons the images I upload to my Drupal website are downsampled.

For example the image I'm uploading is 857x947

I've checked the following settings:
- the size of the CCK ImageField: 420x840
- the size of image cache used to re-sample the image: 420x840

Image Toolkit: Compression: 100%

I'm using cropping functionality. But I'm not dragging a small area, just almost all the original image is selected.

What am I missing ? Maybe php is compressing the image while uploading it ?

Thanks

Comment: anybody with a comment ? It seems to be something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure that it is not caching try to clear all Drupal caches and your browser cache as well.

Then check if the imagecache preset you're using really isn't containing any scale action, just a crop action. To be sure, again just flush the imagecache preset and check the folder that there is no old, wrong image left.

Then go to your content type -> Manage Fields -> your picture field and check if the maximum resolution in there is set correctly.

I'm not aware of any other steps that downsample an image, if you don't have any other image-related modules installed. You wrote that you checked theses things, but most likely one of those steps is responsible.

Comment: hi, I'm actually using imageField crop functionality and scaling with image cache. The resolution is always the same, so I don't get why I get low quality.

Comment: Then there's also the possibility that a small image gets upscaled by ImageField Crop. I would check the files in the imagecache folders, ImageField Crop always leaves the original.

Answer (score 0):

By default Drupal resamples uploaded jpgs to 75% of their original quality.
Change it in this configuration page

```
/admin/settings/image-toolkit
```

Also I noticed that Image Magick library gives better results than default GD, but depends of the format of the image, etc.

Comment: anyway, the images are png. I'm using GD. I cannot change... The point is that the quality drops a lot... it is clear the image is not high quality as before.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do not use any imagestyle effect and whatever the setting at /admin/settings/image-toolkit the image will always be altered, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246398/image-derivative-size-different-from-original-even-in-absence-of-any-effect and the related Drupal 7 core issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2914964